# Activity Restarting when I press back navigation button

Tags: java, android, android-intent

So I basically I have implemented some on back pressed method for my notification where I am trying to intent appropriate activity and when one press back button it gets him to tabs of the main activity. It is working fine when the user is logged in but when a person is not logged in the MainActivity. it has a function sendtostart which redirects the person to login page. On that Start activity when I press the back button. Activity keeps on restarting itself rather than going in the background. I have tried to override the on back pressed method over there but failed.

My code of MainActivity Looks like this:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mRootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.main_app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Chit Chat");

        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {


            mUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

        }


        //Tabs
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.tab_pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        mTabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tab);
        mTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);


        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(new LifecycleObserver() {
            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP)
            public void onStop(){
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                if(currentUser != null) {
                    mUserRef.child("online").setValue(ServerValue.TIMESTAMP);
                }
            }

            @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
            public void onStart(){
                //onstart action here
                // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
                FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

                if(currentUser != null && currentUser.isEmailVerified()){
//                    intentExtra = getIntent().getStringExtra("backPressed");

                    mUserRef.child("online").setValue("true");


                } else {
                    sendToStart();

                }


                }


        });
```

where sendtoStart is:

```
    private void sendToStart() {

    Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
    startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

    startActivity(startIntent);
    finish();

}
```

This is how I am shifting to Tabs based on intent value:

```
  @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if(intentExtra != null) {
            if (intentExtra.equals("notification")) {
                TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_tab);
                TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(1);
                tab.select();


            }


            }
        }
```

Please let me know if any coding part you want. I have tried everything from finding a solution on the Internet to Debugging my self but couldn't find the fix.

Comment: I think you can call `onCreate` in `onResume` ?! not sure it is good idea, but it is an idea

Comment: Why onCreate in OnResume?

Comment: to rebuild activity, or I think much better will be rebuild

Comment: I don't get you

Comment: On your activity class you have `onResume` and inside body of it call `recreate()` method and that should help you

Comment: What to pass in recreate method?

Comment: `getIntent().getExtras()` I thinks, that should help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
Intent startIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
    // set the new task and clear flags
startIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(startIntent);
finish();
```

Comment: @Rehan are you storing your session after you login? And do you check if you are logged in when open app from background? That should prevent you to re login.

Comment: Still It takes one time back press to go to home launcher, and when reopen it again it takes 2 times back button to go back and this goes on.

Comment: Don't get you, please explain the scenario with Activity name what is happening right now and what do you want?

Comment: Ok so basically When I open activity and user is not loggede in it pushes me to Start activity with the above Intent code. When I press back it doesn't go back but when I press it again it goes back, When I reopen my app from recent button, now when I press back button three time than the application gets out to the Home Launcher and this continue to increase no of back presses. Hope this clear my Question.

Comment: I don't know but it is working correctly on emulator but creating problems on my phone